# Glass Block Pass Through

Tags: coaxial-cable, feed-line

In my future shack I will have glass block windows consisting of 6 x 8 blocks and a 6 x 16 vent. I've been searching, but cannot find the best solution to pass coax through the windows.  I've thought about machining a plastic block to insert in the vent and insert bulkheads through the plastic block, and I've thought about replacing a glass block with a dryer vent, but that is unsatisfactory.

I'm looking for ideas to pass coax through a glass block window. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not go through something other than the window? You can drill a hole in glass, but drilling through any other construction common material is probably easier.

Comment: What's a glass block window? A thin sheet of glass like a regular window, or a glass brick  50-100 mm deep, laid like a regular masonry brick?  Also please add: what frequencies you're planning to operate, and at what power level?

Comment: @tomnexus certainly the latter. For example: https://www.lowes.com/pl/Glass-block-windows-Windows-Windows-doors/4294772371

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II I agree I wouldn't want to drill through glass.  I'm thinking of something I could use to replace one of the glass blocks, most likely.

Comment: What frequencies are you planning to operate, and at what power level? I'm thinking of using a thin coax, perhaps 1 or 2 mm diameter, pushed through a hole on the mortar / grout between blocks...

Comment: HF and eventually VHF up to 600W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a short jumper of a thin cable, pushed through a hole drilled in the grout between the blocks, or next to them in the plaster.
[image: 141 semi-rigid coaxial cable]
A 141-size cable is 3.6 mm in diameter, and the base model with teflon / copper [claims to handle 600 W up to 500 MHz](https://www.ezform.com/product/ez-141-tpm17/) so that might be an option. You'd need some N-type connectors for the thin cable on both sides of the window, it's not flexible enough to go to your rig.

The power limit is a thermal limit, so must be derated for SWR > 1:1, but if it's 600 W PEP then it will be be OK with 1.5:1 SWR. If the SWR is very high and you have a tuner inside, then it might only cope with 100-200 W.

Comment: This is a good idea.  Thanks!